# apache2 server hosted on linux is not accessible over LAN

Tags: linux, networking, apache-http-server, python, web-hosting

I am trying to access my apache2 server which is hosted on a Debian based linux system over the local network but unfortunately it is not being accessible. 
While i try to access it as `localhost` or `192.168.1.x`(through ip address) it is accessible on local machine but while at LAN it is not being accessible. 
I also tried fresh installation of apache2 server and tried to fix, but nothing useful..

I modified `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` file where I commented `Listen *:80` line and changed it to  `Listen 0.0.0.0:80`

Also, I modified `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` file where I changed the line `VirtualHost *:80` to `VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:80` 
As far as I am aware, there is no firewall running on the system or any sorts of iptabe rules.

While I try the netstat command it shows:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7780/apache2
```

nmap the ip `192.168.1.x` also shows that the port is open.

Furthermore, While trying to server the content through  `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080` the content is only accessible on local machine but not on LAN. 
I doubt that it is some sort of networking or port forwarding issue or such. I might be mistaken here though!

Can anyone please help me to sort out the problem and help me find out what I am missing here?

Comment: show iptables -L -v please

Comment: Everything seems to be accepting here `Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)`
`Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)`
`Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)`

Comment: Update: I restarted the apache2 server and I got that there are no packets movement in the forward chain `Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1908 packets, 3564K bytes)` `Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)` `Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1858 packets, 1866K bytes)`

Comment: ok, that seems to be not a firewall issue, try check ifconfig, Your PC has valid IP address and it's on the same subnet as other PCs which can't connect. Also check route -n output.

Comment: For instance, my system is `192.168.1.5` and the gateway is `192.168.1`. The system that is trying to connect to `192.168.1.5` is `192.168.1.6` | The `route -n` shows `Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface`
`0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlan0`
`192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlan0` which seems good I guess | however 'ifconfig' shows that I have ipv6 address in use whereas I have turned of ipv6 through 'NetworkManager' the ipv4 thing seems good... still confused!

Comment: ok, one more check. what shows "curl 192.168.1.5"? please run from 192.168.1.6.

Comment: `curl --head 192.168.1.5` gives `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` while trying to access from `192.168.1.6` PS: In this instance the `.1.6` was another virtual system(virtual box) used on the same system which was using bridged connection and the network was routed through `192.168.1.1` (gateway). However, while trying to access the system `192.168.1.5` from another computer from `192.168.1.7` it is still not accessible. I am completely amused to see this issue and still cant figure out what I am missing here!!!

Comment: hmm, I'm out of ideas. In case where curl returns HTTP 200, it must work. In other cases where it is not accessible, I think it's time to learn some tcpdump and try it on both send and receive sides.

Comment: There must be something wrong with your network configuration. Can you ping from the host that doesn't work? All these addresses are on the same link, so the gateway has no role when these hosts communicate with each other.